# MemoryError when importing Micropython file

Tags: machine-learning, out-of-memory, esp32, micropython

I am running a Machine Learning model on an ESP32 which operates with Micropython. To infer the model, I trained a Random Forest Classification Model within Python using SciKitLearn library. To export the model, I used the [m2cgen](https://github.com/BayesWitnesses/m2cgen) library which converts the model to plain python code.

The resulting python file is approximately 873 KB in size and looks like the following:

```
def add_vectors(v1, v2):
    return [sum(i) for i in zip(v1, v2)]
def mul_vector_number(v1, num):
    return [i * num for i in v1]
def score(input):
    if input[31] <= 14182.0:
        if input[12] <= -7552.0:
            if input[43] <= -2098.0:
                if input[49] <= -2522.0:
                    if input[58] <= -4395.5:
                        if input[3] <= 4716.5:
                            if input[45] <= 4954.0:
                                if input[34] <= 1353.5:
                                    var0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
                                else:
                                    var0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                            else:
                                var0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
                        else:
                            var0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]

[...]

return mul_vector_number(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(add_vectors(var46, var47), var48), var49), var50), var51), var52), var53), var54), var55), var56), var57), var58), var59), var60), var61), var62), var63), var64), var65), var66), var67), var68), var69), var70), var71), var72), var73), var74), var75), var76), var77), var78), var79), var80), var81), var82), var83), var84), var85), var86), var87), var88), var89), var90), var91), var92), var93), var94), var95), var96), var97), var98), var99), var100), 0.01)
```

I then want to store this file on an ESP32 microcontroller, flashed with MicroPython, in order to infer the model.

When uploading the file into the Flash memory of the ESP32, everything works fine. (Flash size is around 4 MB, of which 2 MB is available for the user). Then I tried to import the file in the main.py file on the ESP32 to utilize the score function.

```
from rf_model import score
```

However, when running the script, the program throws the following error:

```
MemoryError: Memory allocation failed, allocating 136 bytes
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is running out of RAM. Flash size doesn't matter (altough 873 KB - wow, that's *massive*) because all the variables and other runtime overhead is allocated in RAM and there's not enough of it. The ESP32 has only 520 KiB of internal RAM, of that only 320 KiB is used for data (the rest for code running in RAM). The Python interpreter already takes up a large chunk of that and your script is left with whatever RAM remains after that. In short - you won't be doing much heavy lifting.

Assuming your current board doesn't already have external RAM, one potential solution is to get a board with as much external RAM as possible. Espressif has [several devkits](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/devkits) with 8 MiB PSRAM (price differences are a few euros so I'd buy the beefiest of them - [ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1-N32R8V](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/hw-reference/esp32s3/user-guide-devkitc-1.html)). They also sell the rather cumbersome [ESP32-S3-BOX-3](https://github.com/espressif/esp-box) with 16 MiB PSRAM - this is actually intended for AI applications.

Maybe one of those will provide enough RAM for your script. There's no guarantee, obviously, until you're able to predict the worst case RAM usage of your script.